# resourceProviderFactoryType is ignored in web.config file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, localization, globalization

I have been trying to set a custom resourceProviderFactory at the web.config file but its always ignored, my web.config file looks like the following

```
<globalization culture="auto" resourceProviderFactoryType="MyProject.CustomResourceFactory, MyProject"></globalization>
```

My CustomResourceFactory class is never fired, setting a breakpoint at the constructor is never reached.

Misspelling the class name in the globalization section does not raise any exceptions, is that normal ?

I've tried this in more than one project (thinking that the project I'm working on is misconfigured or something) but the same results.

I'm using C# asp.net MVC3,

Does anyone have a clue why this happens, and is there a way to change the ResourceProviderFactory at runtime ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue, and didn't quite understand your comment on the first answer.  Now that I've solved it I do, but I thought I'd elaborate for anyone else.

http://publicityson.blogspot.ca/2010/11/aspnet-mvc-razor-view-engine-and.html

He created helpers to call his custom resources as the razor requirement of calling
`ViewContext.HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(classKey, resourceKey)` in the view is really long, which resulted in something like:

```
public static class CommonHtmlExtensions
{
    public static object GetGlobalResource(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string classKey, string resourceKey)
    {
        return htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(classKey, resourceKey);
    }
    //several other methods.
}
```

Allowing him to use `@Html.GetGlobalResource("CommonText", "Some_ResourceKey")` in a razor view.

Also very useful to keep things strongly typed and usable in dataannotations, the link below shows how to use T4 templates to create constants for every resource item in your database.
http://carrarini.blogspot.ca/2010/08/localize-aspnet-mvc-2-dataannotations.html

Comment: Isn't it weird that this setting has just plain disapeared?

Answer (score 0):

Doing some reflections on razor views in mvc3, i didnt see any evidence of using this resourceProviderFactory, and thats why your custom resource provider is not touched, i guess this feature is not meant to be used in MVC and its only availble for Web Forms,

using resources in MVC shall be by just pointing to your Resx generated class, exmaple:

```
    @
    {
       var resources = MyResources.ResourceClass;
    }

<p>@resources.MyTitle</p>
```

and if you want to use a custom class that loads your resources, you can simply point the variable **resources** above to a diffrent class,

but here is also another way that i think could achive it.

you can change the **pageBaseType** in the web.config in the Views folder to your own class that inherits from WebViewPage

in this class you can create a property that return an instance of a custom class that loads your resources.

By doing that you can later access this property at any view in the Views folder.

do whatever fits your situation. and if there is a better way please share it.

Comment: Well I found that if doing HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(..) it goes in my provider. I've built custom dataannotation attributes diriving from base ones and html helper to display localized text (Html.Localize(type, key))